# Could a Djinn be killed by a silver bullet dipped in lamb’s blood?

Tags: supernatural

Given that Crowley made bullets from a melted down angel blade, it would imply that killing creatures with knives is less about the knife and more about the penetration and death.

By that logic, anything they kill with knives could be shot by the equivalent materials. We see this with Dean using wrought iron bullets on ghosts.

I guess the better question is, why still bother with silver, gold, brass knives. When they would all be easier to replace with bullets. Or is the blade part an important part of the lore?

Comment: Not sure, not familiar with the source material - but it might matter that knives are much more reusable than bullets.  Even if the materials are always perfectly reclaimed, there's effort again in recasting... and a single knife's material worth of bullets might not go so far in a fight as an actual knife.

Comment: I don't think we know what specifically about the Angel Blades make them deadly, but the Colt's bullets involved charms scratched into the bullet, and I think the same was true of the demon-killing knives.  So it would depend on what you're trying to kill.  A Djinn I expect would depend on if firing the bullet would burn off the blood as it's fired - so, any ballistics experts around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supernatural tends to play fast & loose with their lore availability and implementation. For example, as you noted, Dean does use Wrought-Iron bullets for ghosts in the first season, but for the rest of the series you see that their ghost bullets are just salt shells, and Iron is introduced as melee weapons. I can't recall any reason the change was made other than him adjusting to having Sam around (thus increasing probability of friendly fire from said iron). We see them etching an itty bitty devil's trap into small-caliber bullets can keep a demon from smoking out, but they don't do that with any other rune or ward in the series.

Also, in the meta perspective, the vast majority of their source material was written prior to guns being invented, and in usually some less than direct means. I could see Supernatural introducing a Robert-Neville-inspired character that hunts down monsters solely for the purpose of experiment on ways of killing them outside of the show's existing lore... but our Wayward Sons are nearly always firmly in the camp of "How do I kill it?" and move on to the next threat/episode. They're not going to be the ones inventing & producing a (I don't know... glass?) bullet that contains sheep's blood and silver, but if another character donates a clip of said bullets, they'll certainly use them.

In-universe, I could see Hunters having this very conversation, and having silver & brass bullets (not gold bullets, unless there's a Hunter with the last name of Trump)... but still bringing along the knives in case. Hunters in the show are massively practical - Knives & swords have multiple uses, don't need to be reloaded, can't misfire, and can easily be used by distressed victims if the Hunter is disarmed.